# Fixing Lisp Syntax

Tags: programming-languages, syntax, lisp, scheme

Being a newbie to Lisp I'm wondering if the Lisp syntax could be "fixed"?

Some people say the syntax in Lisp is one of its biggest strengths. I don't quite understand this.

Isn't it possible to replace "obvious" parentheses with a combination of white spaces, new lines and indenting? Just like in Python?

It looks to me like parentheses are the most used characters in Lisp code. I'm wondering if that's true - but if it is, isn't this a suggestion, that there is some redundancy in the syntax?

Is there some simple answer to the question - why so many parentheses?

For example:

```
(defun factorial (x)
    (if (= x 0)
        1
        (* x 
           (factorial (- x 1)))))
```

Why not:

```
defun factorial (x)
  if (= x 0)
    1
    * x
      factorial
        - x 1
```

e.g. close parentheses at the end of line, and always open them on new lines. 
Only the 1 would be ambiguous - is it 1 or (1) - but we could introduce an exception - single tokens are not "listified".

Could this work?

Edit:

Thank you all! I see now there are some [links](http://www.lispin.org/wiki?page=default/links) at the lispin [site](http://www.lispin.org).

Comment: What you are talking is not syntax, it's punctuation.
syntax would be ( a b c ) or ( a c b ) type decision.

Comment: My kingdom for an “else” keyword!

Comment: @marcus You could always use defmacro for an if/else that takes an else keyword; all you have to do is never expand the 'else' parameter, only the two body forms.

Comment: I don't program in Lisp much (if at all). I just read some code snippets here and there, and I find it hard to tell where important things begin and end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you suggest appears to have been implemented in <s>[Lispin](http://www.lispin.org/)</s>

**Edit:** [sindikat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596361/sindikat) points out in the comments below that the link is no longer valid. Here's the last valid version of the site from the Web Archive: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20080517144846id_/http://www.lispin.org/

Comment: Interesting... is the converse true, e.g. is there a variant of Python that uses parentheses instead of indentation?

Comment: i'm sure there would be one if python were also 50 years old... :)

Comment: "is there a variant of Python that uses parenthesis" -- probably.  Just look back in history for a simpler variant of Lisp predating Common Lisp.  Of course, it will be lacking the large library support modern Python distributions contain.

Answer (score 31):

You'll change your mind once you write a couple of macros.

Comment: THIS answer should be accepted as the answer (though it's pretty terse). Macros are EXACTLY why the parens are so awesome. Given the question was "would removing the parens break lisp?", the answer can be found here.

Comment: you can have equally powerful macro systems for more complex syntax (see slate as an example), but macros are complex enough using simple lists denoting programs, so very few people bother with powerful macrosystems working on AST's of syntax-rich languages.

Comment: @Attila, power and simplicity are not inversely related. Point taken though.

Comment: Dylan is a paren-free infix Lisp and it still includes macros. Common Lisp as implemented needs its syntax to write macros, but parens aren't inherent to the concept of macros.

Comment: Lisp macros don't work over s-expressions. S-expressions with parentheses, lists, symbols etc. are only an external representation. Lisp macros work over internal data. How the expressions are externally represented is independent of macros.

Comment: @Chuck, I wasn't saying that parens are what make macros possible. @Rainer, you're right. But it seems to me Lisp's insistence on parens for structuring code eases the cognitive load when reasoning about macros.

Answer (score 28):

It's been done lots of times (a < twenty line preprocessor will do wonders).  But there is also an advantage to having them explicit.  It drives home the parallelism between code and data, and in a way leads you out of the sort of thinking that makes you find them annoying.

You could (for an analogous example) take an object oriented language and remove all the syntactic grouping of methods into classes (so they became, in effect, overloaded functions).  This would let you look at it more as you would a straight imperative language, but something would be lost as well.

When you look at lisp you're supposed to think "Everything is a list.  Ommm"

(Well, Ok, the "Ommm" is optional).

Answer (score 20):

"Perhaps this process should be regarded as a rite of passage for Lisp hackers."

-- Steele and Gabriel, "The Evolution of Lisp", 1993

Answer (score 9):

Several times I've compared Lisp code and equivalent code in other languages.  Lisp code has more parens, but if you count all grouping characters []{}() in other languages, Lisp has fewer parens than all these.  It's not more verbose: it's more consistent!

When seen from this point of view, the "problem" is simply that Lisp uses one type of construct (lists) for everything.  And this is the basis for its macros, its object system, a couple of its most powerful looping constructs, and so on.  What you see as a minor style issue (would brackets look cooler?  probably) is actually a sign of language power.

That said, Lisp is all about giving power to the programmer.  If you want, write your own dialect that lets you do this.  Lisp (unlike some languages I could mention!) is all about programmer power, so use it.  If you can make it work, maybe it'll take off.  I don't think it will, but there's nothing to stop you from trying, and you'll learn a lot either way.

Answer (score 6):

The point of lisp "syntax" is its non-existence.  An s-expression is a tree of identities, where the tree structure is denoted by parens (**and** indentation).  It's worth noting that sexps were meant to be a low-level representation only, but people ended up liking it more and kept using it.

What **an expression** means to the execution engine **is incredibly flexible** in lisp and it's also **context sensitive.**

In other languages, the level of context sensitivity is much lower and the set of building blocks you can use to build your own abstractions is much less freely extensible.  Therefore, special syntax denoting the few given constructs is fitting the picture.

In lisp, I can change the meaning of everything, even in a context sensitive manner.  Having special syntax for a few predefined constructs would be silly because I may end up using my own 'if', or my own specialized closures, etc..  What if my new 'if' needs 4 arguments (e.g. to group certain if's of a program and tell some groups to always fail or succeed in certain situations)? How should I extend the syntax of the predefined 'if'? It's much easier to resort to the AST (sexps), but then why bother with special syntax at all?

Also note that using an editor like emacs makes it very easy to edit such a tree in a structured way.  For example, having a key to transpose two nodes in a tree is equally useful to swap variable declarations and to swap two statements in a program block (hint: that's why the "extra" parens are useful in let, cond, etc.).

So, that's the reasoning why **the non-syntax of lisp is** so **appealing to many people who got used to the idea of extending the language** instead of bending the problem to fit a predefined set of tools... but it doesn't mean that syntax sugar is not used for user-given constructs!

Some examples of user defined syntax that we use:

- [cl-syntax-sugar](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-syntax-sugar/) - the most notable extension is the `[]` parens used for tiny closures where you don't want to name the closure's variables
- [cl-quasi-quote](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-quasi-quote/present-class.html) - most notably the `<xml >` syntax to inline the xhtml generation in lisp code (please note that this syntax is provided by a **user** library, and it can be enabled in a context sensitive manner)

Comment: Lisp usually has a two-stage syntax. Data syntax with S-expressions and program syntax over s-expressions. Both are syntax - which is concerned with the structure of valid 'sentences' (programs) in language (Lisp).

Answer (score 5):

It could work. It's called [Dylan](http://wiki.opendylan.org/wiki/view.dsp?title=Dylan%20Language%20FAQ).

Comment: i'd put it like this instead: "one can try, it's called dylan"... :)

Answer (score 5):

Even [Paul Graham](http://www.paulgraham.com/), a vocal advocate for the Lisp family of languages, has removed some parentheses from his own dialect [Arc](http://www.paulgraham.com/arc.html):

> Note to Lisp hackers: If you're used to the conventional Lisp
>   `cond` operator, this if amounts to the same thing, but with fewer
>   parentheses.  E.g.
>
> ```
> (cond (a b)
>       (c d)
>       (t e))
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> (if a b
>     c d
>     e)
> ```

(from the [Arc Tutorial](http://ycombinator.com/arc/tut.txt))

Comment: The problem is that the parentheses provide grouping and that's missing from Graham's IF. With COND I place the cursor between two clauses and press m-t (that's: exchange sexp) and they get exchanged. I can move clause up or down.

Comment: @Rainer, my largest Lisp program was a quantum simulator and compiler. Small. So I can't even decide which I prefer. I can, however, say that your "Domain Specific Language" screencast was inspiring. It was a pleasure to see an experienced Lisp hacker at work.

Comment: @Frank That's for the positive feedback.

About 'deciding'. That's part of the 'Lisp experience'. With some experimenting you learn to acquire some 'taste' what looks good AND feels good. 'Feels' means, what is easy to manipulate with the text editor AND the Lisp system. Code is data. Data is code.

Comment: this arc example is a great characerisation of why i don't like arc: playing with lisp's syntax will not yield anything interesting, becuase one of the point of lisp is exactly its non-syntax-ness. small changes to the syntax will not characterize a dialect at all, it'll merely yield a new one.

Comment: Sure Lisp has syntax, lots. Syntax is about the structure of valid expressions in a language. Check out the syntax for the Common Lisp constructs in the HyperSpec - it is defined on top of s-expressions. Some is built-in, some is implemented via macros.

Lisp is for playing with syntax.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of people™: those who process information by means of built-in stack machine in their brains, and those who consume it in large chunks or blocks. These groups are mutually incompatible with each other; they read different books, have different writing styles and, most importantly, write code in different programming languages. I belong to the second group; however, I know many fellow programmers from the first group.

For people in the first group, there is absolutely nothing wrong with nested clauses and subclauses; they grasp recursion naturally; they look at the code slowly, statement by statement, line by line, and stack machine in their brains keeps counting braces and parentheses at the subconscious level. Lisp syntax is quite natural to them. Hell, they probably *invented* stack machines and Forth language. But show them, say, Python (oh noes!), and they will glance helplessly to sheets of code, unable to understand why these stupid code blocks are *left open*, with no matching closing statements.

For us, poor guys in the second group, there is no other option but group code statements into *blocks*, and visually indent them. We look to screen filled with code, first noticing large-scale structure, then separate functions or methods, then statements groups within these methods, then lines and statements, from top to bottom. We cannot think linearly; we need visual boundaries and clean indentation policies. Hence, we cannot bend ourselves to work with Lisp; for us, it is an irregular mess of keywords and silly parentheses.

Most programming languages are compatible with both ways of thinking (those "blocks" are there for reason). Notable exceptions are Lisp and Forth, which are first group only, and Python, which is second group only. I don't think you need to adapt Lisp to your way of thinking if you belong to the second group. If you still need a functional language, try Haskell. It is a functional language designed for people who think in blocks, not stacks.

Comment: this theory sounds nice, but i'm a block kind of guy and i'm most productive in lisp. i even have strong rules how to indent lisp variable declarations, boolean expressions, etc... to help my block-parser when i get back to the code later.

Comment: Lisp has a standard indentation style that gives you your blocks.  You won't see the parentheses anymore after a short while.

Comment: I don't buy this, I think that any smart person could go between the two with minimal problem.

Comment: Nice Lisp code has a standard indentation that makes 'blocks' visual. It also relies on a lot of structural conventions and layouts for those. The visual triggers for these conventions need to be learned and they are mostly based on naming conventions using symbols and not on special characters.

Comment: I don't think this theory is true. Both Python and Common Lisp are my favorite programming languages.

Comment: How about enforcing non-lying-indentation? This discussion is a lot of "x or y" but it's a false dichotomy! You can have indenting AND make the compiler check that the indenting is congruent with the paren.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of why:

It's main use as far as i know is readability, so that people who look at your code can decipher it more easily.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the links, I found this one - [Indentation-sensitive syntax](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-49/srfi-49.html) - there is also Guile module, that implements this syntax, so one could directly try it.

A quite [promising](http://www.paulgraham.com/arcll1.html) Lisp dialect (Arc) could be found [here](http://arclanguage.org/). (I guess one should first some real code see how it feels)

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion on this is: don't use newlines and indentation as "implicit" separators (I also don't like implicit grouping by operator precedence, but that is a different, although related topic).

Example:  Is this valid Python?  Does it do what you expect?

```
if foo < 0 :
    bar
  else :
    baz
quuz
```

I have a little proposal: we could use a preprocessor to indent Python code automatically, by putting special characters into the code that tell it where a statement begins and ends.  How about parentheses for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Clojure. Lesser parentheses but more syntax to remember.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried out and written couple of syntaxes that rely on indentation. At the best results the whole syntax has changed it's nature and therefore the language has turned from one to another. Good indentation-based syntax isn't anything near lisp anymore.

The trouble of giving syntactic meaning for indentation doesn't rise from the idiots and \t vs. whitespace debating. Tokenizing is neither a trouble since reading newlines and spaces shouldn't be harder than anything else. The hardest thing is to determine what indentation should mean where it appears, and how to add meaning to it without making too complicated syntax for the language.

I am starting to consider original lisp style syntax is after all better when you minimize the amount of parenthesis with some clever programming. This can be done, not so easily in current lisp implementations, but in future lisp implementations it can be done easier. It's fast and simple to parse when there's only couple of rules you have to tokenize, and nearly no parsing at all.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old, but I've decided to contribute, because I've created a very similar [reader system](http://www.cliki.net/cl-2dsyntax).

EDIT: Some samples of usage:

```
!defun fact (n)
  if (zerop n)
    1
    * n
      fact
        (1- n)
```

```
!defun fact !n
  if !zerop n
    1
    !* n !fact !1- n
```

For more information check the homepage of project.

Comment: This is effectively a link only answer, which is frowned upon here. Please provide some content/context/sample of the "language" your reader reads.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [alternate Racket Syntax](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader.html?q=at%20syntax&utm_content=buffer67913&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer#(tech._~40._form)).

```
@foo{blah blah blah}
```

reads as

```
(foo "blah blah blah")
```